# MongoDB: Variable nested in several objects

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a problem creating a query in MongoDB. I have the following JSON. How to ask mongodb question to get _id from level5 object?

```json
{
  "Id": "1",
  "level1": {
    "level2": {
      "level3": {
        "level4": {
          "level5": {
            "_id": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#std-label-document-dot-notation) to get value from nested object:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            value: "$level1.level2.level3.level4.level5._id"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AW5RNAlf1gb)

Comment: Need by aggregations not by find?

Comment: Just showing the way you can access it, same dot notation can be used for filtering etc. Nothing prevents you from fetching entire document and accessing that property in your code, what is your use-case?